# Where do conditional statements without brackets end?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a conditional statement without brackets in a function:

```
function get_user_id() 
{
    if ($something) $this->some_function($str);
    return array('user_id' => $user_id);
}
```

I think bracketless statements are bad practice... I want to add brackets to the if-statement but where does the statement end? Does is it end at the first semicolon or the end of the function?

Which is correct:

```
function get_user_id() 
{
    if ($something)
    {
       $this->some_function($str);
    }
    return array('user_id' => $user_id);
}
```

or..

```
function get_user_id() 
{
   if ($something)
   {
      $this->some_function($str);
      return array('user_id' => $user_id);
   }           
}
```

Comment: It's not a bad practice per se, more a question of preference. If you've been coding for several years, they shouldn't be a problem and be easily spottable by your experienced programmer eyes. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version is correct, as without braces, only **one** statement after the `if` statement applies to the conditions of the `if` statement.

So this:

```
if ($something) $this->some_function($str);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if ($something) {
    $this->some_function($str);
}
```

I do agree that [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) is a bit vague about this, but its example is about a single statement, and mentions that in order to incorporate additional lines to the same conditional, you would need a "statement group", denoted by curly braces:

> Often you'd want to have more than one statement to be executed
>   conditionally. Instead, you can group several statements into a
>   statement group.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the first version is correct.  Take a look at the examples in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 1):

First one is correct. One of the reason is that second wont return any array if the condition is false, which is not a good practice.

```
 if ($something)
    {
       $this->some_function($str);
    }
 return array('user_id' => $user_id);
```

for that you need extra code to make it fault tolerant.